Segfault al intentar recorrer una lista enlazada
Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar listas enlazadas en C. En mi programa tengo dos funciones una para crear una lista simplemente enlazada y otra para recorrer e imprimir por pantalla esta. La primera función se ejecuta sin problema pero la función para recorrer la lista me da segfault. He revisado varias veces el código y comparado otros código que recorren listas enlazadas pero no consigo ver mi error. Mi código es el siguiente:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int info;
    struct Node *next;
} NODE;

void create_list(NODE *, NODE *, NODE *);
void print_list(NODE *, NODE *);

int main(void) {
    NODE *list;
    NODE *index;
    NODE *new;

    create_list(list, index, new);
    print_list(list, index);
    return 0;
}

void create_list(NODE *list, NODE *index, NODE *new) {
    int num;
    list=NULL;
    index=NULL;
    printf("Type a negative number to stop.\nInfo: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while(num>0) {
        new=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE)); 
        if(new==NULL) { //  Check if new node is created.
            puts("\nERROR: couldn't access dynamic memory.\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        new->info=num;
        new->next=NULL;
        if(list==NULL) {
            list=new;
            index=new;
        } else {
            index->next=new;
            index=new;
        }
        printf("Info: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }

}

void print_list(NODE *list, NODE *index) {
    index=list;
    while(index!=NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", index->info);
        index=index->next;
    }
}

Muchas gracias de antemano por vuestro tiempo.

Creo que estas buscando el problema en la función equivocada... create_list crea tu lista, pero esa lista creada es local, no puedes acceder a ella desde main y por tanto tampoco desde print_list.

Compilé el código en varios compiladores C y ninguno presentó errores excepto que entra en un bucle y solo sale si se ingresa un número negativo.
El código compila sin errores pero el error está en la creación de la lista enlazada.
El puntero declarado está siendo pasado por valor y los cambios hechos dentro no se reflejarán fuera de la función y la lista e índice no fueron inicializados de la forma que deberían ser.
El problema es que cualquier alteración en lista e índice no se verá y la consecuencia de esto es que cuando se presente la lista no aparecerá nada.
*corrección:
void create_list(NODE **list, NODE **index, NODE **new); 

Corrección main
int main(void) {
    NODE *list = NULL;
    NODE *index = NULL;
    NODE *new = NULL;

    create_list(&list, &index, &new);
    print_list(list, index);
    return 0;
}

Corrección  create_list
void create_list(NODE **list, NODE **index, NODE **new) {
    int num;
    list=NULL;
    index=NULL;
    printf("Type a negative number to stop.\nInfo: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while(num>0) {
        *new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE)); 
        if(*new==NULL) {.
            puts("\nERROR: couldn't access dynamic memory.\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        
        (*new)->info = num;
        (*new)->next = NULL;

        if (*list == NULL) { 
            *list = *new;
            *index = *new;
        } else {
            (*index)->next = *new;
            *index = *new;
        }

        printf("Info: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }
}

Corrección print_list
void print_list(NODE *list) {
    NODE *index = list;
    while (index != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", index->info);
        index = index->next;
    }
}


El puntero doble es un puntero a otro puntero que modifica el valor
del puntero original. Los 3 valores pasados en la función son para
actualizar y crear nuevos nodos en la lista, lo que en el código no se
estaba actualizando.

void create_list(NODE **list, NODE **index, NODE **new);

Además de hacer la pasada por referencia, actualiza las modificaciones y crea el nodo.
*cod completo
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int info;
    struct Node *next;
} NODE;

void create_list(NODE **list, NODE **index, NODE **new);
void print_list(NODE *list);

int main(void) {
    NODE *list = NULL;
    NODE *index = NULL;
    NODE *new = NULL;
    create_list(&list, &index, &new);
    print_list(list);

    return 0;
}

void create_list(NODE **list, NODE **index, NODE **new) {
    int num;
    *list = NULL;
    *index = NULL;
    printf("Type a negative number to stop.\nInfo: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    
    while (num >= 0) {
        *new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE)); 
        if (*new == NULL) { 
            puts("\nERROR: couldn't access dynamic memory.\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        (*new)->info = num;
        (*new)->next = NULL;
        if (*list == NULL) { 
            *list = *new;
            *index = *new;
        } else {
            (*index)->next = *new;
            *index = *new;
        }

        printf("Info: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }
}

void print_list(NODE *list) {
    NODE *index = list;
    while (index != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", index->info);
        index = index->next;
    }
}


Estás buscando el error donde no es, la violación del segmento se produce en print_list, pero no tiene su origen en ella. Vamos a simplificar tu código bastante:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct Node
{
    int info;
    struct Node *next;
} NODE;

void crear_lista(NODE *);

int main() {
    NODE *lista = NULL;
    crear_lista(lista);
    printf("En main: %d\n", lista->info);
    free(lista);
}


void crear_lista(NODE *lista){
    NODE *new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE)); 
    if(new == NULL) { //  Check if new node is created.
        puts("\nERROR: couldn't access dynamic memory.\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    new->next = NULL;
    new->info = 7;
    lista = new;
    printf("En crear_lista: %d\n", lista->info);

}

Este código es susceptible del mismo SegFault también y no estamos recorriendo la lista (que tiene un solo nodo por cierto). El error se produce en el main en la linea:
printf("En main: %d\n", lista->info);

¿Por qué? Pues porque lista en este punto sigue siendo un puntero a NULL (en tu caso list es un puntero a vete a saber, ya que no lo inicializas en main...). ¿Entonces que a pasado con la lista que se crea correctamente en crear_lista?
Lo primero, en C los argumentos se pasan por valor, esto:
crear_lista(lista);

le pasa a la función el valor del puntero lista. La variable lista dentro de la función crear_lista será un puntero con el mismo valor que el puntero lista de main. Cuando luego en la función se hace lista = new; se está asignando a la variable local un nuevo valor, pero esto no va a reflejarse fuera de la función, el puntero lista de main va a seguir siendo nulo. Si tenemos esto en cuenta, no es de extrañar que printf("En main: %d\n", lista->info); genere un SegFault.
Si quieres reasignar un nuevo valor a a la variable y que se refleje fuera de la función puedes pasar un puntero. Es este caso la variable susceptible de reasignarse es un puntero, luego tendrás que pasar un puntero a un puntero:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct Node
{
    int info;
    struct Node *next;
} NODE;

void crear_lista(NODE **);

int main() {
    NODE *lista = NULL;
    crear_lista(&lista);
    printf("En main: %d\n", lista->info);
    free(lista);
}


void crear_lista(NODE **lista){
    NODE *new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE)); 
    if(new == NULL) { //  Check if new node is created.
        puts("\nERROR: couldn't access dynamic memory.\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    new->next = NULL;
    new->info = 7;
    *lista = new;
    printf("En crear_lista: %d\n", (*lista)->info);

}

El argumento se sigue pasando por valor (no hay otra forma), pero en este caso estamos pasando un puntero al punterolista de main. Ahora al hacer  *lista = new; en crear_lista no se modifica el valor de la variable local directamente, sino que se modifica hacia donde apunta el puntero interno, por lo que  el cambio si será visible fuera de la función.
Tu código quedaría algo así:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int info;
    struct Node *next;
} NODE;

void create_list(NODE **);
void print_list(NODE *);

int main(void) {
    NODE *list = NULL;

    create_list(&list);
    print_list(list);
    
    NODE *next_node;
    while(list != NULL)
    {
        next_node = list->next;
        free(list);
        list = next_node;
    }
}

void create_list(NODE **list) {
    if(*list != NULL) {
        puts("\nWARNING: passed reference to non-null list. Potential memory leaks\n");
        *list = NULL;
        }

    int num;
    NODE *new = NULL;
    NODE *index = NULL;   

    printf("Type a negative number to stop.\nInfo: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while(num > 0) {
        new = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE)); 
        if(new == NULL) { //  Check if new node is created.
            puts("\nERROR: couldn't access dynamic memory.\n");
            exit(-1);
        }

        new->info = num;
        new->next = NULL;

        if(*list == NULL) {
            *list = new;
        } else {
            index->next = new;
        }
        index = new;

        printf("Info: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }

}

void print_list(NODE* list) {
    NODE *index = list;
    while(index != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", index->info);
        index = index->next;
    }
}

Algunos apuntes:

No te olvides nunca de liberar la memoria dinámica asignada, en este caso se hace al final del main, pero puedes crear una función que se encargue de ello, eso si, siempre pásale el primer nodo de la lista ya que ha de iterarse sobre todos ellos. Si el dato de tus nodos también usara memoria dinámica deberás liberarla también.

Ten cuidado con este tipo de reasignaciones cuando usas memoria dinámica:
void create_list(NODE **list) {
    *list = NULL;

Si por ejemplo se llamara a create_list pasándole una lista no nula, si hacemos *list = NULL sin liberar el espacio usado por la lista anterior previamente estaremos generando fugas de memoria en nuestro programa.

No le veo mucho sentido que también pases index y new a las funciones, puedes hacerlo igual que con list, pero es complicarse la vida con respecto a usar simples variables locales.

En realidad sería todo más simple si tu función creara la lista y la retornara, en vez de andar con punteros de un lado para otro...


